# Tuple Unpacking in Map Operations

Tags: scala, dictionary, iterator, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I frequently find myself working with Lists, Seqs, and Iterators of Tuples and would like to do something like the following,

```
val arrayOfTuples = List((1, "Two"), (3, "Four"))
arrayOfTuples.map { (e1: Int, e2: String) => e1.toString + e2 }
```

However, the compiler never seems to agree with this syntax.  Instead, I end up writing,

```
arrayOfTuples.map { 
    t => 
    val e1 = t._1
    val e2 = t._2
    e1.toString + e2 
}
```

Which is just silly.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

A work around is to use `case` :

```
arrayOfTuples map {case (e1: Int, e2: String) => e1.toString + e2}
```

Comment: And you don't even need to type the tuple elements. case (e1, e2) => is good enough, the types of the tuple elements are known.

Answer (score 33):

I like the tupled function; it's both convenient and not least, type safe:

```
import Function.tupled
arrayOfTuples map tupled { (e1, e2) => e1.toString + e2 }
```

Answer (score 18):

Why don't you use

```
arrayOfTuples.map {t => t._1.toString + t._2 }
```

If you need the parameters multiple time, or different order, or in a nested structure, where _ doesn't work,

```
arrayOfTuples map {case (i, s) => i.toString + s}
```

seems to be a short, but readable form.

Comment: I guess the main reason is that most of the time, the processing of the map function is far more complicated than `_.toString + _` and he wants to manipulate more comprehensible names than `t._1` and `t._2`.

Comment: Well, then `arrayOfTuples map {case (i, s) => i.toString + s}` is, of course, more handy. However, you should ask the question you have, to get the answer you need. :)

Comment: Well, as he said "frequently", I hope it means "in different cases" i don't see any scenario where you frequently need an `Int + String` mapping. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Another option is

```
arrayOfTuples.map { 
    t => 
    val (e1,e2) = t
    e1.toString + e2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting in `Scala 3`, [parameter untupling](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html) has been extended, allowing such a syntax:

```
// val tuples = List((1, "Two"), (3, "Four"))
tuples.map(_.toString + _)
// List[String] = List("1Two", "3Four")
```

where each `_` refers in order to the associated tuple part.

Answer (score 2):

I think [for comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) is the most natural solution here:

```
for ((e1, e2) <- arrayOfTuples) yield {
  e1.toString + e2
}
```