# In Scala, how do I assign the tuple values to variables in a binary operation of Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tuple Unpacking in Map Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905207/tuple-unpacking-in-map-operations)

Lets say that I have the following Map[Int,Double]:

```
scala> map
res19: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(1 -> 1.1, 2 -> 2.2)
```

I can run the following foldLeft on it:

```
scala> map.foldLeft("A")((initVal,x:(Int,Double)) => initVal + x._1)
res20: java.lang.String = A12
```

But I can't find a way to assign the tuple's values to named variables:

```
scala> map.foldLeft("A")((init,x:(a:Int,b:Double)) => init + x.a)
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but ':' found.
   map.foldLeft("A")((init,x:(a:Int,b:Double)) => init + x.a)
                               ^
```

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use case

```
map.foldLeft("A") {case (init, (a,b)) => init + a}
```

Comment: very cool. So what's the official name of this technique? So  I can read on it.

Comment: I think it's officially called a destructuring bind. [This article](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/03/functions-using-case-statements.html) gives a little insight into how it's used here.

Comment: It's a form of pattern matching.