# Scala collections: why do we need a case statement to extract values tuples in higher order functions?

Tags: scala

Related to [Tuple Unpacking in Map Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905207/tuple-unpacking-in-map-operations), I don't understand why do we need a `case` (that looks like a partial function to me) to extract values from tuple, like that:

```
arrayOfTuples map {case (e1, e2) => e1.toString + e2}
```

Instead of extracting in the same way it works in `foldLeft`, for example

```
def sum(list: List[Int]): Int = list.foldLeft(0)((r,c) => r+c)
```

Anyway we don't specify the type of parameters in the first case, so why do we need the `case` statement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because in Scala function argument lists and tuples are not a unified concept as they are in Haskell and other functional languages. So a function:

```
(t: (Int, Int)) => ...
```

is not the same thing as a function:

```
(e1: Int, e2: Int) => ...
```

In the first case you can use pattern matching to extract the tuple elements, and that's always done using `case` syntax. Actually, the expression:

```
{case (e1, e2) => ...}
```

is shorthand for:

```
t => t match {case (e1, e2) => ...}
```

There has been some discussions about unifying tuples and function argument lists, but there are complications regarding Java overloading rules, and also default/named arguments. So, I think it's unlikely the concepts will ever be unified in Scala.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Even in Haskell, a function f taking two parameters f :: a -> b -> c is different from a function g taking a 2-tuple as its only parameter g :: (a,b) -> c. You translate between these two functions using currying: f = curry g. The advantage of Haskell is, that you can pattern match directly in the parameter declaration. But this works with any type constructor, not only for tuples:  h (Just x) = x + 1. With Scala you must invoke pattern matching explicitly (using "match" or "case").

Comment: You're mixing things up. The Haskell function `f :: a -> b -> c` corresponds to the Scala function `f: A => B => C` or method `def f(x: A)(y: B): C`. The Haskell function `g :: (a, b) -> c` corresponds to the Scala function `g: ((A, B)) => C` or method `def g(t: (A, B)): C`. The Scala function `h: (A, B) => C` or method `def h(x: A, y: B): C` cannot be called with one argument and thus has no correspondence in Haskell. But you are correct that Haskell can do pattern matching in parameter lists while Scala cannot.

Comment: Dotty (which will eventually become Scala 3) now automatically tuples function parameters.

Answer (score 5):

## Lambda with one primitive parameter

With

```
var listOfInt=(1 to 100).toList
listOfInt.foldRight(0)((current,acc)=>current+acc)
```

you have a lambda function operating on two parameter.

## Lambda with one parameter of type tuple

With

```
var listOfTuple=List((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3," "))
listOfTuple.map(x => x._1.toString + x._2.toString)
```

you have a lambda function working on one parameter (of type `Tuple2[Int, String]`)

Both works fine with type inference.

## Partial lambda with one parameter

With

```
listOfTuple.map{case (x,y) => x.toString + y.toString}
```

you have a lambda function, working with one parameter (of type `Tuple2[Int, String]`). This lambda function then uses `Tuple2.unapply` internally to decompose the one parameter in multiple values. This still works fine with type inference. The `case` is needed for the decomposition ("pattern matching") of the value.

This example is a little bit unintuitive, because unapply returns a Tuple as its result. In this special case there might indeed be a trick, so Scala uses the provided tuple directly. But I am not really aware of such a trick.

## Update: Lambda function with currying

Indeed there is a trick. With

```
import Function.tupled
listOfTuple map tupled{(x,y) => x.toString + y.toString}
```

you can directly work with the tuple. But of course this is really a trick: You provide a function operating on two parameters and not with a tuple. `tupled` then takes that function and changes it to a different function, operating on a tuple. This technique is also called [uncurrying](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry).

## Remark:

The `y.toString` is superfluous when `y` is already a string. This is not considered good style. I leave it in for the sake of the example. You should omit it in real code.

Comment: Regarding the `y.toString` - I just took the first `foldLeft` I could find in google, the ones in our project were way too complicated for an example.

Comment: Great! I do not understand why `listOfTuple.map{case (x,y) => x.toString + y.toString}` is called partial lambda. It seems to me we have used all parameters.